# What is difference between content://contacts/people and content://contacts/

Tags: android

I'm reading about content provider and little confused about contact picking from android. I read a lot examples from the Stackoverflow and confused some people are using `content://contacts/people` as Uri and some are using `content://contacts/` as Uri what is difference between them?

And also to access information from the Uri some are using `People.NUMBER` or `People.NAME` and some are using `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` or `Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` can you elaborate them?

Comment: I believe the `people` API was deprecated a long, long time ago but people still use it because of out-dated/bad examples.  Everything in Contacts should be retrieve via the `ContactsContracts` API. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content providers you are reffering to are deprecated since API level 5.

Please use [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) to learn about how to retrieve the list of contacts :-)

---

As a side note, the two providers you asked about are used to access different levels of the contacts database. First you get the general level database, then you have a table of `People` and then each person has tables for `Phones`, `Extensions` and `ContactMethods` etc. [[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html)]

If I remember correctly, the general call mapped to `People` table anyway. Still, please **do not use this ContentProvider**, it is **deprecated**.

Comment: Hi I'm little confused which ContentProvider is deprecated?

Comment: content://contacts and everything further down this path. Please use the linked wrapper

Comment: would you like to give your answer on here too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678071/accessing-contacts-with-intent-and-without-intent-android I have created another question related to Contact API.